# Can not load symbols when profiling on Azure webrole with VS 2013

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Tried a lot different things, but what should be a simple thing never works for me. VSP file downloaded, but doesn't show my function names, only hex codes. It does give an error:

> Error    1    DA0002: It appears that the file was collected without properly setting the environment variables with VSPerfCLREnv.cmd. Symbols for managed binaries may not resolve.    C:\work\AbleAzure\Downloaded Profiling Logs\AbleAzureWeb24201441226PM\AbleWebRCore_0_(f1da3c).vsp    0    0

I checked the folder C:\work\AbleAzure\Downloaded Profiling Logs\AbleAzureWeb24201441226PM, it has all the PDB files in it.

I have no idea about the error *"the file was collected without properly setting the environment variables"*, is it the Azure side or local? I don't see any place to set variable for Azure side.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you make the call to VSPerfReport to visualize your report, you need to specify the symbol locations:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255404.aspx

They must match the versions etc.